# The name 'divisionIDs' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a method that queries the database for a list of GUIDs and then adds them to an array. I would like my method to return one particular GUID from the array (based on the combo box selection index). The following attempt yields the error in the title.

```
public string PopulateDivisions(string qs, string cs)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(qs, connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal("Name");
                Div_Selecter.Items.Add(reader.GetString(ordinal));
                //Data_Result.Items.Add(reader.GetString(ordinal));
            }
            Div_Selecter.SelectedIndex = 1;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int ordinal2 = reader.GetOrdinal("Id");
                for (int i=0; i<=ordinal2; i++)
                {
                    string[] divisionIDs = new string[i];
                    divisionIDs[i] = reader.GetString(ordinal2);
                }
            }
            string selectedDivisionID = divisionIDs[Div_Selecter.SelectedIndex];
            return selectedDivisionID;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you check your `divisionIDs array` , i don't think you can read again from `datareader`  it's a forward only control .

Comment: As side note `string[] divisionIDs = new string[i]; divisionIDs[i] = reader.GetString(ordinal2);` will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `divisionIDs` in the for block, so you don't have access to it outside of that block. you're attempting to use it just outside the while loop. if you need to use that variable outside of the loop, declare it before the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to access divisionIDs outside of the scope it is declared.

```
string selectedDivisionID = divisionIDs[Div_Selecter.SelectedIndex];
```

divisionIDs is declared inside of the for loop inside the while loop, you need to declare the variable outside of the while loop so the scope is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you can not iterate through `SqlDataReader` again as you did here,

```
 while (reader.Read())
            {
                int ordinal2 = reader.GetOrdinal("Id");
                for (int i=0; i<=ordinal2; i++)
                {
                    string[] divisionIDs = new string[i];
                    divisionIDs[i] = reader.GetString(ordinal2);
                }
            }
```

`SqlDataReader` is a forward only , so you can not iterate through it again, You can use `Dataset` for iterating multiple times .
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)